# RichEditBox don't scroll horizontal when table is pasted in it

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have one RichEditBox, like given below. Basically I want to paste a table in it but it doesn't scroll in horizontal direction. If I write any long line below it then I can see the remaining table content. you can download table from [here](http://sdrv.ms/12alknB). Is it any bug in RichEditBox or any solution for that available ? Thanks.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RichEditBox 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
        Width="300" 
        TextWrapping="NoWrap"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This seems to be [known issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bd1ed3ac-ca67-47ee-bc14-41e57e8fda86).